# what is the max size of payload for Pub/Sub message via Google IoT core?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I am using Google Cloud IoT core with Pub/Sub topics. I have a python script from which i am publishing data to my cloud functions via MQTT Bridge.

```
'/devices/{}/events/Topic'.format(device_id) #Topic
```

Now my question is how large the payload can be sent via MQTT?
I have seen two documentations...
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas
&
https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas
and in both the limits are quite different e.g. for Pub/Sub its 10Mb/message and for IoT is 256kb/message ..
So is that means i can only send max 256 kb of payload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the maximum payload size should be the smaller of the two limits, 256 KB.

Comment: But if we use e.g. Http instead of MQTT?then what would be the size?

Comment: Looking here  https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas  ... we see a line which reads "Telemetry event payload - 256KB" ... this doesn't appear to distinguish between HTTP or MQTT as the device -> Cloud IOT transport .... as such, I think it it is a fixed 256KB irrespective of transport.   Is 256KB not sufficient?  What kind and size of content are you thinking of ingesting from an IoT device?

Comment: Thanks @Kolban.. It is a bit higher then "256KB aroung 20KB.. is there any workaround to solve this?

Comment: You could consider doing some transformation / compression on your data to bring it under 256KB for transport, and then decoding it on the receiving end.

Comment: @Hsn ... in your last post you alluded to the size being 20KB ... I think that was a typo .. .did you mean 20MB?

Comment: i meant around 20KB more.. 256KB+20KB

Comment: Actually the payload varies w.r.t some conditions... sometimes it is far less than 256KB and some time higher than 256KB